# how to put the middle button 5px up than other in scrollview in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

[image: I want the middle button to be 5 px high than other button]

Like suppose when i scroll the gallery the button which comes in the middle will shift 5px up than the other So whatever button comes up in the middle it will be little up than other. So please help me

```
        scrlview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 350, 320, 130)];
        [scrlview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 0)];
        scrlview.delegate=self;

            scrlview.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
            scrlview.scrollsToTop=NO;
            [self.view addSubview:scrlview];

            btn1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn1.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 55, 50);
            [btn1 setTitle:@"Btn1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [scrlview addSubview:btn1];

            btn2=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn2.frame=CGRectMake(70, 10, 55, 50);
            [btn2 setTitle:@"Btn2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [scrlview addSubview:btn2];

            btn3=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn3.frame=CGRectMake(130, 10, 55, 50);
            [btn3 setTitle:@"Btn3" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [scrlview addSubview:btn3];

            btn4=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn4.frame=CGRectMake(190, 10, 55, 50);
            [btn4 setTitle:@"Btn4" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [scrlview addSubview:btn4];

            btn5=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn5.frame=CGRectMake(250, 10, 55, 50);
            [btn5 setTitle:@"Btn5" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [scrlview addSubview:btn5];

            btn6=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn6.frame=CGRectMake(310, 10, 55, 50);
            [btn6 setTitle:@"Btn6" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [scrlview addSubview:btn6];

            btn7=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn7.frame=CGRectMake(370, 10, 55, 50);
            [btn7 setTitle:@"Btn7" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [scrlview addSubview:btn7];

            btn8=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn8.frame=CGRectMake(430, 10, 55, 50);
            [btn8 setTitle:@"Btn8" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [scrlview addSubview:btn8];

            btn9=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn9.frame=CGRectMake(490,10, 55, 50);
            [btn9 setTitle:@"Btn9" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [scrlview addSubview:btn9];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried out your requirement. I have assumed that the offset between buttons and their width is same.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    [self addButtonsToScrollView];
}

- (void)addButtonsToScrollView
{
    NSInteger numberOfButtons = 15;
    //NSInteger visibleButtons = 5;

    //CGFloat totalWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat offset = 5.0f;
    CGFloat buttonWidth = 54.0f;//(totalWidth - ((visibleButtons+1)*offset))/visibleButtons;
    CGFloat buttonHeight = 44.0f;

    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(offset, 10.0f);

    for (int idx = 1; idx<=numberOfButtons; idx++) {

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectZero;
        buttonFrame.origin = origin;
        buttonFrame.size = CGSizeMake(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        button.frame = buttonFrame;

        NSString *titleString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title%d",idx+1];
        [button setTitle:titleString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.tag = idx;

        [self.scrollView addSubview:button];

        origin.x+=buttonWidth+offset;
    }

    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(origin.x, 200.0f)];
}
- (void)adjustCenterButton
{
    //content point is set in such a way that there would be exaclty 5 button visible all the time
    CGPoint contentOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;

    NSUInteger units = floorf(contentOffset.x/59.0f); //buttowidth+offset
    contentOffset.x = units*59.0f;
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:YES];

    NSArray *subViews = [self.scrollView subviews];

    //Finds the tag of button which would be the center button
    //since the visible buttons are 5, 3 is added, 
    NSInteger selecteButtonIndex = floorf(contentOffset.x/(59.0f))+3;

    for (UIView *button in subViews)
    {
        //Just a bypass to remove the scroll indicator
        if (button.tag!=0)
        {
            CGRect frame = button.frame;
            frame.origin.y = (button.tag == selecteButtonIndex)?5.0f:10.0f;
            button.frame = frame;
        }
    }

    CGSize contentSize = self.scrollView.contentSize;
    contentSize.height = 200.0f;//self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = contentSize;
}

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    /*The update is only called when the scrollView is not decelerating.
    The method is an required if the user is scrolling very slowly,
    the other scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: will not be invoked*/
    if(!decelerate)
    {
        [self adjustCenterButton];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self adjustCenterButton];
}
```

Comment: @Anupdas- thank you, when i scroll i want one button to always be on the top(middle one), i tried differnt delegate of scrollview bt havent obtained smooth experience

Comment: @VivekSehrawat I have edited my previous answer. Use setContentOffset:animated: instead of setContentOffset:.

Comment: @Anupdas- the error is coming in that line "No visible interface for UISCROLLVIEW declares the selector setContentOffset:animated",,and suppose when i tried the didscroll delegate than their is no animation

Comment: @VivekSehrawat There was a typo error. I have fixed it. Please try now.

Comment: @Anupdas- great work done, in first time..by using scrollViewDidScroll i m done what was i trying to do, bt the middle button is not exact in the middle, where to change that thing

Comment: As shown in the code snippet, you can use scrollViewDidEndDragging: and scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: to get events when scrolling is finished to update the center button. To make things easier i included an option where in scroll position will center to the button in middle :). If scrollViewDidScroll is used to update button it would keep on updating and will give make the scrollView flicker.

Comment: @Anupdas- Can u give me ur email id..for some discussion

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25512/discussion-between-vivek-sehrawat-and-anupdas)

Answer (score 4):

You can use of loop like for loop or while loop.
Let me give you some idea about that.

**Here i have updated answer with sample code with more clearly**

```
NSArray *yourArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"btn1",@"btn2",@"btn3",@"btn4",@"btn5",@"btn6",@"btn7", nil];

int xPos = 10;
for (int i = 0 ; i < yourArray.count; i ++) {

    int yPos = 30;
    if (i == (yourArray.count /2)) {
        yPos = 25;
    }

    UIButton *button =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame=CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, 55, 50);
    button.tag = i;
    [button setTitle:[yourArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [scrollView addSubview:button];
    xPos+=55;
}

[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(xPos+10, 55)];

// To get Center Button

UIButton *centerButton = (UIButton *)[scrlview viewWithTag:(yourArray.count /2)];
```

May be this will be help you.
All the best !!!

Comment: @yashesh- thank you. but how will i know which button is in center..?

Comment: @VivekSehrawat for example you have **NSArray** so you can specify **yourArray.count** instead of **10**. and instead of **i== 5** you can put **yourArrar.count/2**. And when ever you want that center button then just done one thing that..  **UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:yourArray.count/2];**

Comment: @VivekSehrawat i have updated the answer with sample code... still you have any dought then tell me ... :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25494/discussion-between-yashesh-and-vivek-sehrawat)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
for(UIButton *subview in yourScrollView.subviews)
{
    CGRect subviewRect = [yourScrollView convertRect:subview.frame fromView:subview];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(subviewRect,middlePointOfScrollView))
    {
        // change y position of button
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u, bt can u elaborate more

Comment: @VivekSehrawat you need to reset the position according to scroll no? The array elements are always same.. How will you get the current middle buttn.. My answer is for finding the middle button dynamically..